# Integrating two event handling programs in Python

Tags: python, qt, events, event-handling, pyqtgraph

I have two programs in Python. Let's call them Prog1.py and Prog2.py . Prog1 is helping me get live data from an external device. As of now, as and when it gets the data it prints it on the screen. There is a while loop running where in each iteration it prints out the new set of data acquired. Now Prog2 is a Python program built using PyQtGraph which is intended to plot the data real time like that of a monitor. As of now what Prog2 does is that (that is, when it is run separately), it plots the already acquired data. This is a moving plot. So Prog2.py has an update function which is called repeatedly by a timer at specified intervals so as to update the graph with next data point (to make it move towards the right) . My objective is to link Prog1 and Prog2 - that is somehow I want to pipe the data acquired in real time by Prog1 to Prog2 so that Prog2 can plot the data in real time.

Since Prog1 and Prog2 are independent events having their own event-loop process I am not sure how to link them. One naive idea I thought was to run Prog1.py and Prog2.py in parallel  and ask Prog1.py to save the data to a file (maybe pickle it? ) and ask Prog2.py to read from it and then plot the graph. But I am not convinced by this. This looks dirty. Somehow I want to run the entire Prog2.py code inside Prog1.py. Is there a clean way to do this?

EDIT-
Code

Prog1.py

```
/*

Code to get data from USB

*/

def main():
    while 1:
        data = get_data()
        print data

main()
```

Prog2.py is the PyQtGraph code via to timer to update the graph and make it scrolling

Comment: You could probably accomplish this nicely with threading. Have one thread do all the heavy lifting for the live data and another thread that does the graph. Give the second thread an event which will update the graph and when the first thread grabs the data trigger that event. That is if you want it all in one program like you stated. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects

Comment: I also managed to combine a library(Live555) which has its own event loop with my Qt gui. You can easily achive it with threads as long as you respect to basic threading rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You a few options, probably any of which would work:

1. Join the programs into one, with a worker thread that monitors for data and sends this back to the main thread for plotting. (see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/haiJsGhxTaQ/RkOov_UZEcYJ)
2. Join the programs into a single-threaded program, with a timer that checks for new data, and replots whenever data has arrived:

   ```
   plt = pg.plot()
   def update():
       data = getNewData()
       if data is not None:
           plt.plot(data, clear=True)
   timer = QTimer()
   timer.timeout.connect(update)
   timer.start(10)
   ```
3. Keep the programs separate and use some form of IPC--sockets, pipes, etc. to communicate between them. This would involve serializing the data (probably with pickle, as you suggest). `pyqtgraph.multiprocess` even lets you send Qt signals between processes. This is probably the most difficult option, but here's an easy example:

   ```
   import pyqtgraph as pg
   import pyqtgraph.multiprocess as mp
   proc = mp.QtProcess() # start second process for plotting
   rpg = proc._import('pyqtgraph') 
   plt = rpg.plot() # create a PlotWidget in remote process

   # Unlike the last example, we can use a wile-loop here because the Qt
   # event loop is running in another process.
   while True:
       data = getNewData()
       if data is not None:
           plt.plot(data, clear=True, _callSync='off')
   ```

Comment: In your 2nd suggestion getNewData() is my Prog1.py which is receiving at frequency of 128 (I get 128 data points per second). It has a separate loop which prints the data as it is coming. Your code suggests to call getNewData only at 10 ms gap? Sorry but can you please elaborate a bit more? I have edited my post for more clarity.

Comment: Of course you are free to run the timer at any interval you like. Whether any of these suggestions works for you will depend on the details of your data acquisition (for example, are you required to poll the device with some maximum interval? How long can you wait before data will be dropped?) and on the performance of your system in drawing the data. Using timers (2) is easiest, but if you find that drawing causes unacceptably long delays in data acquisition, then a parallel method (1 or 3) might be more appropriate.